# give custom style to neighbours li with same class (active)

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

I'm trying to give a custom style to neighbours items with the same class, this is the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxfb10L1/2/)

i tried this code, but this gives style to the second, not the first or middle items ..

```
ul li.active+li.active div {
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

the second line describe what i want to do exactly, the same idea if there is more than 2 active items ..
how could i do that using css !

Comment: are you looking like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/bxfb10L1/3/

Comment: How could there be **two** active items?

Comment: By active , OP means `active` class

Comment: @Paulie_D consider it as (selected numbers !), it's not matter the name of class

Comment: are you talking about this ? http://jsfiddle.net/bxfb10L1/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the nature of CSS that selectors are cascading, and that, selectors can only be used to identify elements 'beneath' or *following* the referenced node.

The only available sibling selectors are `+` (immediate following sibling) and `~` (following siblings), you cannot select a preceding or parent element.

If you wish to select both the preceding and following elements, you will need to resort to e.g. jQuery

`$('.active').prev('.active')` and `$('.active').next('.active')`

Comment: Indeed - until [`:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#has-pseudo) is supported that is